# Is there a way to change the refresh time on the RSS Viewer Web Part?

Tags: rss, 2007, web-part

I need to set the RSS Viewer Web Part to a shorter time.  I would like to be able to get the Feed to change shortly (maybe every 10 min).  This is for a News feed in an Intranet site and the posters would like it to change fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it was a setting in Site Collection Level.  The way to change it is

- Go to Site Settings
- In Site Administration Section click on link RSS
- Set the Time To Live(Minutes) filed with required refresh time